# Android TextView line background

Tags: java, android, background, textview

[image]

I'd like to create a textview that contains a blue line as it's background just like in the image I provided. You can also find it in Google calendar when entering appointment info.

I previously tried using 9patch images to stretch the line horizontally and keep the vertical scaling the same.  But that does not work.  I'd like to also use this in other view to provide my own background to other views.  Any hints?

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: if you mean the item that has the color wheel next to it, that is not a textview that is an `EditText` and it shows automatically when focused

Comment: Sorry, meant edittext

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are looking for the `EditText` layout item, not `TextView`. It will automatically change the line to the blue color when the user places the cursor there, otherwise it will be black.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a relativelayout for your edittext, and for the lines, a view 1dp high at it's bottom (width matchparent so it stretches) , and two 1dp wide views at its sides, that'd accomplish that effect (as high as you want them).

Comment: I think this is a good start but i don't think this is the best way to implement this feature.  I'd like to use one drawable...perhaps a 9 patch that stretches horizontally.  But 9 patches stretch in both directions.  Then maybe I can set the drawable as the background. Thank you for the idea.